# How to use GDI functions to draw on a DC which is being used by OpenGL?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, graphics, gdi

How to use GDI functions to draw on a device context (DC) which is being used by OpenGL?

This means how to use GDI functions and OpenGL together. Supposed that I have a DC, and this DC has been used to initialize OpenGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better not do it. Technically mixing OpenGL and GDI only works properly for single buffered windows. For double buffered windows GDI calls make sense only after the buffer swap.

But why do you want to mix OpenGL and GDI after all?

Comment: because i want to use some 2D features of GDI like drawing text (vector font), etc. is it a good thing to do?

Comment: @Paul: I was guessing you'd want to draw text. There are several methods to draw text in OpenGL. The most common is texture mapped fonts, i.e. a font it turned into a texture atlas, then the text drawn from that. Drawback: It won't scale for languages that have thosands of characters. Another method is to render the text into a image (you could do this with GDI into a DIBSECTION DC), then upload that image to OpenGL. Other possible methods include vector textures and distance maps.

Comment: tks daten, vector texture is a nice option :) but then i have to read the vector font file myself, after that draw every character using GL_LINES?

Comment: @Paul: vector textures encode the glyphs shape curve coefficients in a texture and use a shader to implement Beizer rasterization. Technically you'd draw quads, with a set of vertex attributes that selects the glyph's curves. However I suggest you don't implement font rendering yourself, but use one of the available, ready to use OpenGL font rendering libraries.

Comment: what c++ library do you suggest for rendering 3D vector text in opengl?